# JSlider with different steps

Tags: java, swing, jslider

I'm trying to implement a zoom slider which works exactly like the Microsoft Office word.
The central mark represents 100%, and the slider varies from 10 to 500.
How can I define two different steps: one of the [10;100] range and another for the ]100;500] to avoid losing the possibility of incrementing by 1% in each range?

Comment: The slider in my copy of Open Office goes from 20% to 600%.  20% to 100% is half the slider and 100% to 600% is the other half.  The buttons increment and decrement by 5%.  You can position the slider in 1% increments.  I'm guessing this is similar enough to what you're seeing in Word.  To answer your question, write your own JSlider that can handle a BoundedRangeModel with multiple ranges.

Comment: Thank you, can you give me a simple source code for your solution?

Comment: Use google for that .